# Node.js module.exports assignment resulting in method undefined error

Tags: node.js

To make mongoose setup easier, I've created a mongoose.js file in my /lib directory. Its setting up mongoose so consuming modules can have the connection ready etc. The problem is, when trying to access the **mongoose.Schema** method on product.js, it throws method undefined. In doing a similar practice for my own objects, this does not happen. Here is the code in question.

**/lib/mongoose.js** (lib file)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.PPC_API_MONGODB_URL);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('db open');
});

exports = mongoose;
```

**/models/product.js**  (consuming file)

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose.js');

var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({ // results in method undefined here
    name: String
});

exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

I can get this to work if I do the following in /lib/mongoose.js

```
exports.mongoose = mongoose;
```

Then within /models/product.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').mongoose;
```

but this is not clean and I'm simply not understanding why the first option doesn't work.

If you could either show me what I'm doing wrong or explain why the first approach does not work, that would be considered a checked off answer with my up vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't reassign the `exports` variable, but instead you can use `module.exports`

```
module.exports = mongoose;
```

If you're wondering why, what you have in each module is essentially this:

```
var module = { exports: {} };
var exports = module.exports;
```

So if you add properties onto `exports`, you can still access those through `module.exports`

```
exports.test = function () { console.log('test'); };
module.exports.test(); // outputs 'test'
```

But if you reassign `exports`, then `module.exports` and `exports` point to different things.

```
var module = { exports: {} };
var exports = module.exports;

exports = { test: 'test' };

console.log(exports);        // { test: 'test' }
console.log(module.exports); // {}
```

When `require()` looks for what to include, it uses `module.exports`.

Comment: Thanks! That was a very easy fix.

Comment: I appreciate the more detailed explanation. That makes much more sense to me as the "exports" variable is just a reference that's attached to "module". if you reassign then you are erasing the "module" reference. Awesome!!!

Comment: Yep, as a side note, I always use `module.exports` because of all the shortcomings of `exports`. And most important, don't mix your usage of the two within a single file or you'll tend to run into problems.